# Ionic 2 Camera photo not showing

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, camera

I'm working on a simple app which should take a photo with the Camera. The Camera works and takes the picture. However I can't display the image. I get an empty grey box. In this box should the picture appear, which it doesn't. Anybody any idea?

EDIT: When I run the app on the android emulator I can take a photo (built in android function) and show that in the app. Whenever I deploy it via the Ionic View app or in de iOS Emulator I cannot view the image.

EDIT 2: I can run the app on a Android device. I assume that the Ionic View app is sometimes a little bit buggy.

Here is my code :

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            Contact
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <button ion-button (click)="takePicture()">Take photo</button>
    <button ion-button (click)="sendData()">Send</button>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
            <img [src]="base64Image" *ngIf="base64Image" />
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Typescript file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Camera} from 'ionic-native';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-contact',
    templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class ContactPage {

    public base64Image: string;

constructor() {

}

takePicture() {
    Camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: 0,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000
    }).then((imageData) => {
        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your first parameter in getPicture():

`destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,`

Edit: ionic view doesn't play nice with plugins. The only real test you can do is run on a device. I've tried your code and it's running on my android phone.

Comment: Yes I've tested it as well on a Android device and it works. The Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL as you suggest is not working for me. I get an error that it is a private member and therefore not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
Camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        targetWidth: 1000,
        targetHeight: 1000,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        allowEdit:true }).then((imageData)=>{

        this.images.push(imageData);
    });
```

Try the above code. It will work in the iOS emulator.

Comment: Also, the ionic view on iOs has some issues. So make sure you test your code on an emulator or an iOs device.